# How can I see the IP configurations defined for a Virtual Machine Scale Set

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I am working with a VMSS (Virtual Machine Scale Set) and there are many ip configurations defined for the VMSS shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

Where can I see the definition of each ip configurations (shown above) in Azure Portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested in my environment. I created VMSS via both Portal and ARM template.

The NICs created under VMSS cannot be seen in the NICs in the Azure Portal as the resource type will be different :

Resource type of NICs created normally :

**Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/**

Resource type of NICs created under VMSS :

**Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/virtualMachines/networkInterfaces**

IP configurations are done at the NIC level.

For the NICs created under VMSS, we cannot see the IP configurations of the NIC in the portal :

[image]

To see the IP configuration of NIC in a VMSS :

Go to your VMSS --> Click on Instances --> Select any virtual machine instance --> Click on Networking

Select the IP configuration and you want to see and you should be able to see NIC Public IP and  Private IP :

[image]

Additionally, you can see IP configurations of NIC attached to VMSS using below CLI command :

```
az vmss nic list --resource-group RGName --vmss-name VMSSName
```